# Dynamic creation of JSON object from given parameters

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, associative-array, javascript-objects

I have a json object of this type:

```
jsonObject={visits:'3',
        v1:{'timestamp':'1231313.311',
            'time_year':'2011',
            'time_month':'Jan',
            'time_date':'15'
            'X_value':'X'
           },
        v2:{'timestamp':'1231313.311',
            'time_year':'2011',
            'time_month':'Jan',
            'time_date':'15'
            'X_value':'Y'
           },
         v3:{'timestamp':'534224242.311',
            'time_year':'2011',
            'time_month':'Feb',
            'time_date':'5',
            'X_value':'Z'
           }
         }
```

Now i want to convert this into a format like...

```
 JsonObject={'2011':{'Jan':{'15':['X','Y']
                          },
                    'Feb':{'5':'Z'
                          },
                    }
             }
```

How can i do that...I ve tried iterating over the first JSONObject and taking out year,month,and date values but i am not able to create a new JSONObject from that data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not JSON, it is simply a JavaScript object. Your question does not seem to be related to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've tried iterating the original object, you're probably not far from done. You just need to create the new object:

```
var newObject = {};

for(var key in jsonObject) {
    if(key == 'visits')
        continue;

    var year = jsonObject[key]['time_year'];
    var month = jsonObject[key]['time_month'];
    var date = jsonObject[key]['time_date'];

    if(!(year in newObject))
        newObject[year] = {};

    if(!(month in newObject[year]))
        newObject[year][month] = {};

    if(!(date in newObject[year][month]))
        newObject[year][month][date] = [];

    newObject[year][month][date].push(jsonObject[key]['X_value']);
}
```

[JSFiddle demo, outputs into your browser console log](http://jsfiddle.net/keQzu/).